# IMobileServiceSyncTable.Where filter isn't working?

Tags: sqlite, azure-mobile-services

UPDATE: If I hardcode the Where filter using `"f40a0cad-608c-4190-a79e-47af918c087a"` it returns the user, it seems other string fields such as Name or FacebookToken don't work even when hard coded.

I'm using **WindowsAzure.MobileServices 1.3.0-alpha3** and **WindowsAzure.MobileServices.SQLiteStore 1.0.0-alpha3**

I've done this many times before with no issues but I'm having a strange issue where my filter isn't returning anything when I know for a fact it's in the table. Here is my code:

```
public async Task SyncUserAsync(string facebookToken)
{
    await _userTable.PullAsync ();
    var user = (await _userTable.Where(x => x.FacebookToken == facebookToken)
                                .Take (1)
                                .ToEnumerableAsync ())
                                .FirstOrDefault ();
    var userTwo = await _userTable.LookupAsync ("f40a0cad-608c-4190-a79e-47af918c087a");
    if (user != null)
        Debug.WriteLine ("Facebook user {0} is synced", facebookToken);
}
```

This code results in a null `user`, but the `userTwo` lookup returns the user I'm looking for. Even if I copy the `FacebookToken` from `userTwo` and hard code the `Where` filter, it returns null.

Comment: Are the other fields defined in the table (when you run the `DefineTable` method in the `MobileServiceSQLiteStore` instance)? What do you mean when you say that when you filter using that GUID works? Filter based on the `Id` property, or the `FacebookToken` property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `LookupAsync` method does a query based on the **id** of the object. If you want to make the two calls (ToEnumerable and Lookup) equivalent, you'd need to rewrite them as follows:

```
public async Task SyncUserAsync(string facebookToken)
{
    await _userTable.PullAsync ();
    var facebookToken = "f40a0cad-608c-4190-a79e-47af918c087a";
    var user = (await _userTable.Where(x => x.Id == facebookToken)
                                .Take (1)
                                .ToEnumerableAsync ())
                                .FirstOrDefault ();
    var userTwo = await _userTable.LookupAsync (facebookToken);
    if (user != null)
        Debug.WriteLine ("Facebook user {0} is synced", facebookToken);
}
```

*update after comment*

Here's a [complete, self-contained, small(-ish) example](http://sscce.org) which follows the exact scenario which you have:

### Service:

Mobile service, configured with Facebook auth, with one table (User), with the following insert script:

```
function insert(item, user, request) {
    item.facebookToken = user.userId;
    request.execute();
}
```

### Client:

Windows store app (could be other platforms as well). Added the NuGet reference to the latest version of the [Azure Mobile Services SQLiteStore package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.MobileServices.SQLiteStore) (1.0.0-beta).

#### MainPage.xaml:

Blank app with two buttons:

```
<Page
    x:Class="App3.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App3"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button Name="btnPopulateRemote" Content="Populate remote table" Margin="10" FontSize="30"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                Click="btnPopulateRemote_Click"/>
        <Button Name="btnPullAndSearch" Content="Pull and search locally" Margin="10" FontSize="30"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="1"
                Click="btnPullAndSearch_Click"/>
        <TextBox Name="txtDebug" AcceptsReturn="True" Margin="10" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

#### MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.SQLiteStore;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace App3
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public static MobileServiceClient MobileService = new MobileServiceClient(
            "https://MOBILE-SERVICE-NAME.azure-mobile.net/",
            <<YOUR-APP-KEY-GOES-HERE>>
        );

        private const string TestId = "f40a0cad-608c-4190-a79e-47af918c087a";
        private string facebookToken;

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void btnPopulateRemote_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            await InitializeIfNecessary();
            Debug("Populating the remote table...");
            try
            {
                var table = MobileService.GetTable<User>();
                var user = new User
                {
                    Id = "f40a0cad-608c-4190-a79e-47af918c087a",
                    Name = "John Doe"
                };
                await table.InsertAsync(user);
                Debug("Inserted: {0}", user);

                user = new User
                {
                    Id = "01234567-89ab-cdef-0123-456789abcdef",
                    Name = "Jane Roe"
                };
                await table.InsertAsync(user);
                Debug("Inserted: {0}", user);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                TraceError(ex);
            }

            Debug("");
        }

        private void TraceError(Exception ex)
        {
            Debug("Error: {0} - {1}", ex.GetType().Name, ex.Message);
            Exception inner = ex.InnerException;
            while (inner != null)
            {
                Debug("    {0} - {1}", inner.GetType().Name, inner.Message);
                inner = inner.InnerException;
            }
        }

        private async Task InitializeIfNecessary()
        {
            if (MobileService.CurrentUser == null)
            {
                await MobileService.LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Facebook);
                Debug("Logged in as {0}", MobileService.CurrentUser.UserId);
                this.facebookToken = MobileService.CurrentUser.UserId;
                Debug("Using this value for the FacebookToken: {0}", this.facebookToken);
                Debug("");

                Debug("Creating the local store");
                var store = new MobileServiceSQLiteStore("file.db");
                store.DefineTable<User>();
                await MobileService.SyncContext.InitializeAsync(store);
                Debug("Initialized the sync context / local store");

                Debug("");
            }
        }

        private async void btnPullAndSearch_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            await InitializeIfNecessary();
            Debug("Pulling data locally and searching...");
            try
            {
                var _usersTable = MobileService.GetSyncTable<User>();
                await _usersTable.PullAsync();
                Debug("Pulled data into local table");
                var itemsInLocalTable = (await _usersTable.ReadAsync()).Count();
                Debug("There are {0} items in the local table", itemsInLocalTable);

                var user = (await _usersTable.Where(x => x.FacebookToken == facebookToken)
                    .Take(1)
                    .ToEnumerableAsync())
                    .FirstOrDefault();
                Debug("User retrieved: {0}", user);

                var userTwo = await _usersTable.LookupAsync(TestId);
                Debug("User two: {0}", userTwo);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                TraceError(ex);
            }

            Debug("");
        }

        private void Debug(string text, params object[] args)
        {
            if (args != null && args.Length > 0) text = string.Format(text, args);
            this.txtDebug.Text = this.txtDebug.Text + text + Environment.NewLine;
        }
    }

    public class User
    {
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("facebookToken")]
        public string FacebookToken { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("User[{0}, {1}, {2}]", Id, Name, FacebookToken);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the FacebookToken in the database I'm trying to filter on is "Facebook:1406839882938501". x.FacebookToken == "Facebook:1406839882938501" doesn't work though. Neither does x.Name == "Carlin Stulberg" even though I can see that those are the values.

Comment: See the edit above. Can you try to print out all the items which you have in your local table? When you `Lookup` based on that ID, are the values for the FacebookToken field for `userTwo` the ones which you are trying to find?

Comment: First of all, thank you for putting that much time into this answer! That was crazy. I'm using Xamarin Studio and it usually tells me when there are package updates, but I guess because the alpha and beta versions are separate release and not an update (?) it wasn't notifying me. I replaced the alpha version I had with the beta and the same where filter that was returning null now returns the user I expect. Sorry that you had to write all that for it to turn out to just be a package update. The alpha must've had a bug on some filtering?

Comment: Glad it was resolved. It's possible that there was a bug, there have been lots of changes in that code (you can see them at https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-services/tree/offline).